# load each table data to html table using label

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I load each data on my sql server to label?
So far I could only load 1 data.I can't load all of them I can't figure out how to start.
Here is the list of data I want to load.

[image]

My current output: [image]

This is my code:

```
  private string product_name { get; set; }
    private string product_type { get; set; }
    private string image_desc { get; set; }

    private void load_products()
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT productName,productType,image_desc
                               FROM Products3",con);

        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if(rdr.Read())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                product_name = rdr["productName"].ToString();
                product_type = rdr["productType"].ToString();
                image_desc = rdr["image_desc"].ToString();

               // foreach()
                lbl_table.Text = @"<table class='table table-bordered'>
                                   <thead>
                                   <tr>
                                   <th>Product Name</th>
                                   <th>Product Type</th>
                                   <th>Image</th>
                                   </tr>
                                   </thead>
                                   <tbody>
                                   <tr>
                                   <td>"+product_name+@"</td>
                                   <td>"+product_type+@"</td>
                                   <td>"+image_desc+@"</td>
                                   </tr>
                                   </tbody>
                                   </table>";
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

How could I get all the table data?I figured I need some `foreach` but I don't know where to use it.I wanted to create seperate table for each product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define Label text before the while loop like this

```
lbl_table.Text = @"<table class='table table-bordered'>
                               <thead>
                               <tr>
                               <th>Product Name</th>
                               <th>Product Type</th>
                               <th>Image</th>
                               </tr>
                               </thead>
                               <tbody>";
```

Now inside the while loop you need to create only new row for each record like this

```
While()
{
      ...
      lbl_table.Text += @"<tr>
      <td>"+product_name+@"</td>
      <td>"+product_type+@"</td>
      <td>"+image_desc+@"</td>
      </tr>";
}
```

After completing while loop add tags for closing Table

```
lbl_table.Text += @"</tbody></table>";
```

Thats it.

Comment: is this inside the while(rdr.Read)?Because I'm getting error on your while()

Comment: if you want to create separate table for each record then use your previous code as it is just modify it like this `lbl_table.Text +=@"` add + sign